# Jaeger with Spring Boot

Tags: trace, jaeger

In a spring boot application (just one at the moment) I included jaeger by adding dependency `opentracing-spring-jaeger-web-starter` and the below beans

```
@Bean
public static JaegerTracer getTracer() {
    io.jaegertracing.Configuration.SamplerConfiguration samplerConfig =
            io.jaegertracing.Configuration.SamplerConfiguration.fromEnv().withType("const").withParam(1);
    io.jaegertracing.Configuration.ReporterConfiguration reporterConfig =
            io.jaegertracing.Configuration.ReporterConfiguration.fromEnv().withLogSpans(true);
    io.jaegertracing.Configuration config = new io.jaegertracing.Configuration("fooService").withSampler(samplerConfig).withReporter(reporterConfig);
    return config.getTracer();
}

@PostConstruct
public void setProperty() {
    System.setProperty("JAEGER_REPORTER_LOG_SPANS", "true");
}
```

After starting Jaeger in docker `docker run -d --name jaeger -p 16686:16686 -p 6831:6831/udp jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.9` I get the traces.

I found now another dependency and read different tutorials which made me somehow unsure on what is the right way to use Jaeger with spring boot.

**Which dependency would I use?**

https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-cloud

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
  <artifactId>opentracing-spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

https://github.com/signalfx/tracing-examples/tree/master/jaeger-java-spring-boot-web

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-web-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Following the [Jaeger documentation](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-java) possibly

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jaegertracing</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaeger-client</artifactId>
    <version>$jaegerVersion</version>
</dependency>
```

would be enough!?

Before trying Jaeger I used Zipkin which is very easy to integrate in Spring since there is a starter for sleuth. The logs contain trace and span id's in separate fields so they can be searched for e.g. in Kibana. Jaeger does [not](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.16/client-libraries/#value).

**Can that be customized and if so - how?**

Is it possibly to use Jaeger with Brave for instrumentation. The project e.g. includes `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` as a dependency. There are some conflicts with already existing beans. Can Jaeger be used with brave at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to your question about dependencies it is explained here in Dependencies section (https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-jaeger):

> The opentracing-spring-jaeger-web-starter starter is convenience starter that includes both opentracing-spring-jaeger-starter and opentracing-spring-web-starter This means that by including it, simple web Spring Boot microservices include all the necessary dependencies to instrument Web requests / responses and send traces to Jaeger.
>
> The opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter starter is convenience starter that includes both opentracing-spring-jaeger-starter and opentracing-spring-cloud-starter This means that by including it, all parts of the Spring Cloud stack supported by Opentracing will be instrumented

And by the way:

- opentracing.jaeger.log-spans is true by default

same as:

- opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.host=localhost
- opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.port=6831
- opentracing.jaeger.const-sampler.decision=true
- opentracing.jaeger.enabled=true

Answer (score 1):

This link (https://objectpartners.com/2019/04/25/distributed-tracing-with-apache-kafka-and-jaeger/) provides the details of how to enable jaeger traces.

The simplest way to enable jaeger to spring-boot application is add the dependency and the required properties.

---

**Dependency:**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
   <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-web-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Example Properties**

```
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.host=localhost
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.port=6831
opentracing.jaeger.const-sampler.decision=true
opentracing.jaeger.enabled=true
opentracing.jaeger.log-spans=true
opentracing.jaeger.service-name=ms-name
```

Answer (score 0):

To configure the Jaeger we need to add dependency of Jaeger Client in each and every services (in pom.xml).

Jaeger Client Dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
   <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-web-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding dependency we need to add Jaeger Client configuration on each services.

```
@Configuration
public class JaegerConfig {

 
  @Bean
  public JaegerTracer jaegerTracer() {

    return new io.jaegertracing.Configuration("jaeger-client")
        .withSampler(new io.jaegertracing.Configuration.SamplerConfiguration().withType(ConstSampler.TYPE)
        .withParam(1))
        .withReporter(new io.jaegertracing.Configuration.ReporterConfiguration().withLogSpans(true))
        .getTracer();
  }
 

}
```

We can also change the configurtion according to the Sampling strategy that we are using in the Jaeger.
You can refer offical doc for sampling strategy.
[1]: https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.22/sampling/

After setup Jaeger Run

> docker run -d --name jaeger -p 16686:16686 -p 6831:6831/udp
> jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.9

Run Jaeger UI on Port 16686.